# PostgreSQL with wamp

Tags: postgresql, wamp

I have installed WAMP 2.1 on Windows 7 with PHP-5.3.4 and Apache-2.2.17 but instead of MySQL I'm using PostgreSQL version 8.4.

How can configure PostgreSQL on WAMP?

Comment: What exactly do you want to configure?

Comment: I want use php script with postgres connection.

Comment: And your problem is? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I added php_pdo_pgsql and php_pgsql, but the service don't start!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have solved the problem by

- adding `php_pgsql` and `php_pdo_pgsql` extensions
- adding `path-php` in `PATH` environment variable of Windows

Comment: Just a note: make sure you set `PATH` within **system** environment variables and not environment variables for current account... could be troublesome :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Install PostgreSQL
2. Edit php.ini, uncomment “extension=php_pgsql.dll”. Check both the
   php.ini in the PHP folder and Apache folder
3. Edit environment variables, add PostgreSQL /bin and /lib directories
   to Path. This solves the  issue of php_pgsql.dll not loading due to
   it not being able to resolve dependencies.
4. Done. PHP should now be able to communicate with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that WAMP has two `php.ini` files. One in Apache directory, one in php directory (`bin\php\php5.X.X`). Wampserver Tray manages the one in Apache directory.

To be able to run php cli tools (e.g `php artisan`), you need to uncomment the `php_pgsql` and `php_pdo_pgsql` in the `php.ini` in php directory.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [WAPP](http://bitnami.com/stack/wapp). It's a package similar to WAMP but with PostgreSQL instead of MySQL (and PhpPgAdmin instead of PhpMyAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way is add location of PHP Instalation to Environment Path of Windows

Control Panel -> System And Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables.
Under "System Variables" add PHP Installation Dir for "Path" Variables.

Then Restart Apache Web Service
This way is work for me (Windows 7 32 Bit, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.4)