# Postgres installation issue

Tags: php, postgresql, wamp

I have been using Wamp server for a long time now. It comes with MySQL. Today I had to change from mysql to PostgreSQL. I've tried install Postgres, downloaded and completed the installation. But when I tried to run a php program to reteive some data from the table,

```
<?php
$link = pg_connect("host=192.168.2.43 dbname=DataFetcher user=postgres password=user");
echo "Connection Established";
?>
```

it says `Call to undefined function pg_connect()`, that means Postgres is not detected.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Was your PHP version built with Postgresql support? Check `phpinfo()` and have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php.

Comment: Can you connect to Postgres using it's commandline tool `psql`?

Comment: no..Im a starter in postgres, I was trying to install it and wnt to know mre abt it by using it..bt I cnt get this thing started

Comment: What happens when you try to connect throuh `psql`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL with wamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218692/postgresql-with-wamp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I installed wamp, enabled php_pgsql and php_pdo_pgsql successfully. But I was still unable to see pgsql installed on apache server. I found a nice explanation and solution provided by @skoobiedu at http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,40270,40311

P.S. I have again given this answer because this is the correct answer for this question and @Bill deleted my answer. I request @user1371896 to accept this answer as correct answer. I also request @bill not to delete this answer as I have already removed same answer from one other post.

Comment: I had given same answer on one more posted question. So he deleted my answer. I didn't know that we can't give same answers to different posts. Actually i should have given you the link to the duplicate answer. And by the way now i have deleted the duplicate answer. now this is the only answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the extention.

Something like left click wamp icon goto - php > extentions and click php_pgsql.

Comment: should I disable anything related to mysql?

Comment: @user1371896 Have you restarted the server?

Comment: @user1371896 No, it has nothing related with mysql.

Comment: anything to be changed in the file php.ini

Comment: @user1371896 Can you find `php_pgsql.dll` in your system?

Comment: also check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php, I could nt understand what they have said there..

Comment: I found the file php_pgsql.dll

Comment: This is fairly clearly an issue with not having the extension. Create a page containing just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. This will let you view your PHP setup. If the extension doesn't get listed on the resulting page, then its not installed correctly. This isn't a problem with postgresql and definitely not mysql.

Comment: The php_pgsql extension doesnt get listed when I tried phpinfo function.. so is it some error with my wamp??? my wamp server was wrking fine til this time.. no other issues other than when Im using psotgres

Comment: @user1371896 Do you have any line in your php.ini which says `extension=php_pgsql.dll`? And if so, is it active (meaning it's not commented out with an ";" at the beginning.